# ssh to remote server with password in jenkins without ssh plugin

Tags: jenkins, ssh

Can I do ssh to remote server with password without using jenkins plugin and public /private key concept ? Also can I make jenkins pipleline interactive by asking parameter value to user during runtime?

I tried it by 'execute shell' option but its not working

Answer (score 0):

It's a while since I worked in this area, but I seem to remember that one computer logging into a second machine using SSH needed to have a trust relationship set up. User name and password would not work (at least under Linux)